# Set a username and password for TWRequest (with ACAccount) in order to see specific user's home timline

Tags: objective-c, ios, twrequest, acaccount

I am trying to access a specific user's home timeline, so that I can see the tweets that the user would see on his timeline when he logs into twitter.  I have the username and password, but can not find how to link this up to the TWRequest.  I have looked for creating an ACAccount and handling the TWRequest with that, but could not find ways to link it up to a specific user name and password.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks.